# Access data from from two lists based on lookup columns and insert into another

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am new in SharePoint and is stuck in some problem.

I want to insert data in to a list by fetching data from 2 lists.
The scenario is :
List A Columns : EmployeeName, EmployeeID, EmployeeSalary 
List B Columns : DepartmentName, EmployeeID, ManagerID

EmployeeID is lookup column

I want to fetch data from these 2 lists and insert data into another list:
List C Columns: EmployeeName, EmployeeSalary, DepartmentName

Can someone please explain me all the possible approaches to do the above task

Comment: On what event will List C will be populated? I mean occasion when List C should be populated?

Comment: You can create all these 3 column as lookup column in ListC

Comment: thanks for comment. I want to insert data into List C when data is inserted in the List A

Comment: Which sharepoint version you are using? And are you using any tool for workflow in sharepoint or it's just SharePoint workflow.